# I want to create an API in API Connect to modify request headers

Tags: api, apiconnect

I want to create an API in API Connect such that the API will be able to modify the incoming request to include a new header on top of the existing header and this information will be extracted from the gateway URL. If the gateway URL is https://api.us.apiconnect.ibmcloud.com/cloud-microservices-unit-dev/sb, then the extra field(say 'env') added to the request message header will contain env=us.

Comment: True for fetching the catalog address I can do what you have said. But if you check my post my main concern was to modify the request message header. How to add a new field in the request message header in API Connect gatewayscript policy? @EliShere

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you require the catalog name.
You can either use the `env.path` context variable (v5 compatible mode only) or split and take the 2nd argument of the host header using `request.headers.host` context variable.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_2018/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/rapim_context_var.html for more information.

Comment: True for fetching the catalog address I can do what you have said. But if you check my post my main concern was to modify the request message header. How to add a new field in the request message header in API Connect gatewayscript policy?

Comment: see example here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/rapim_gwscript_codesnip.html